# Sparql query for provenance metadata

Tags: sparql, rdf

Following resaource has provenance metadata as a graph:

http://geo.linkeddata.es/resource/Provincia/Madrid

and here is the turtle serialization:

http://geo.linkeddata.es/data/resource/ComunidadAut%C3%B3noma/Comunidad%20de%20Madrid?output=ttl

And I am trying to access provenance metadata with following SPARQL query to the endpoint http://geo.linkeddata.es/sparql:

```
SELECT ?y WHERE {
    ?x foaf:primaryTopic <http://geo.linkeddata.es/resource/Provincia/Madrid> .
    ?x rdf:type ?y.
    }
```

But it returns null, and I can't understand where is my mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queries :

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT * WHERE {
   GRAPH ?g { ?x foaf:primaryTopic ?y .}
    } 
LIMIT 10
```

and

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT * WHERE {
   ?x foaf:primaryTopic ?y .
    } 
LIMIT 10
```

Return no answer on your endpoint : http://geo.linkeddata.es/sparql

Therefore the property foaf:primaryTopic is definitely not used in the data accessible through the endpoint.

Then why does this property appear in the serialization http://geo.linkeddata.es/data/resource/ComunidadAut%C3%B3noma/Comunidad%20de%20Madrid?output=ttl ?

I guess this link is a document generated from the data contained in the endpoint, but with additional information on the document itself that are not contained in the original endpoint. Typically :

```
<http://geo.linkeddata.es/data/resource/ComunidadAut%C3%B3noma/Comunidad%20de%20Madrid?output=ttl>
      rdfs:label "RDF description of Comunidad de Madrid" ;
      foaf:primaryTopic <http://geo.linkeddata.es/resource/ComunidadAut%C3%B3noma/Comunidad%20de%20Madrid> .
```

I hope it helps and that I made myself clear.

Comment: thanks @daxid! Your idea is reasonable. The provenance information seems to be an automatic information of access time to the document instead of a real creation time of the data. I was wondering how did you end up with the idea of keeping this document data in another endpoint (which seems reasonable again)? Is there any document that I can read about this practical stuff? Or is there a possibility that they don't keep that information at all?

Comment: I think there might be a little misunderstanding. I have nothing to do with http://geo.linkeddata.es/ and the way things work there. I just inferred  stuff from a few observations.

If you want some documentation, I think they are using Virtuoso and that the way it exposes data related to an object in a web page or in a downloadable ttl document might be described somewhere in Virtuoso documentation (I never used this endpoint, so...).

Comment: Another clarification : The web page http://geo.linkeddata.es/resource/Provincia/Madrid shows the data related to the instance <http://geo.linkeddata.es/resource/Provincia/Madrid> in the SPARQL endpoint. The URL http://geo.linkeddata.es/data/resource/Provincia/Madrid?output=ttl is an export of those data in ttl format, but it adds information about the "document" itself, namely <http://geo.linkeddata.es/data/resource/Provincia/Madrid?output=ttl>. This additional information is not contained in any endpoint. It is just added to the ttl file when generated at download time.